# Time series interpolation with non linear time

Tags: python, pandas

I have the follow pandas table and I would like to do the interpolation. But the data point is not linearly separated so there are problem when I directly use `interpolate()` function in pandas.

Are there any way that I can do the interpolation and the function could take care of the non-linear time?

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08-14 05:55:25 | 0 |
| 2022-08-14 05:56:05 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:01:12 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:01:28 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:01:42 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:01:52 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:02:12 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:06:37 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:07:20 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:07:50 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:08:00 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:08:17 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:08:26 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:09:46 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:09:50 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:10:10 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:13:52 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:15:22 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:15:32 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:15:43 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:16:03 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:17:04 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:17:14 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:17:24 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:17:34 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:17:54 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:23:16 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:23:26 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:23:39 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:24:09 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:25:04 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:25:14 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:25:40 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:25:50 |  |
| 2022-08-14 06:26:00 | 26 |

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the interpolation is linear you can create a function and apply the function on the dataframe. The interpolation is: `value_2-value_1/(date_2-date_1) * (date - date_1)` where date is the input, and date1, date2, value1, value 2 is the date of the first and last row and the value of the first and last row.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just think of a way to get the linear time by creating a linear time series (with 1 second interval), use pandas interpolate function and then lookup my value in the interpolated dataframe. But I think there should be some smarter way to deal with this problem.

Comment: Yes, a function is faster, especially if the time difference becomes larger (why use a look up table with discrete values when a function is which maps the time continuous to a continuous solution). If you have a reproducible code example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) we can help you and produce an example of what is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, I create a linear time series dataframe, set the first and last value, run the interpolation and do the lookup.

```
    # Find the start time and the end time
    startTime = originaldf.loc[firstIndex]['Time']
    endTime = originaldf.loc[lastIndex]['Time']

    # Create linear time series dataframe for interpolation
    interpolatedf = pd.DataFrame({
        'Time': pd.date_range(start=startTime, end=endTime, freq='S'),
                                 })
    interpolatedf.at[interpolatedf.index[0], 'Value'] = 0
    interpolatedf.at[interpolatedf.index[-1], 'Value'] = 26
    interpolatedf['cloestStopPointInterpolation'].interpolate(inplace=True)

    # Do a interpolate value lookup
    originaldf= pd.merge(originaldf,interpolatedf,on=['Time'],how='left')
```